# Wordpress overwriting my quite spesific rule

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Wordpress automatically ads a paragraph tag inside a div (class "intro-description") that I have created. As this new p tag has some top and bottom margin by default, I tried adding a rule to cancel out this effect:

```
   .intro-description p {
       margin: 0;
    }
```

Why doesn't this work? The margins are still there.

Answer (score 2):

You use `!important` to be more specific:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.intro-description p {
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-description">
  <p>Test (without margin)</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Test (with margin)</p>
</div>
```

or you can use a more specific CSS rule instead of `!important` (recommended):

```
[other elements here] div.intro-description p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

> You can find more information about specificity here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity